# не работает qsort c++

Tags: c++, функции, сортировка

код должен сортировать числа, но выдаёт ошибку. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int comp(const int* i, const int* j)
{
    return *i - *j;
}



int main() {
    int n;
    bool compare=true;
    cin >> n;
    int* arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
        qsort(arr, sizeof(int), comp);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[j] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: А если `int comp(const void* i, const void* j)`?

Comment: тогда ещё больше ошибок выдаёт, и старые остаються

Comment: Вам уже дали ответ ниже)

Comment: Зачем вам `qsort` в C++? Есть же замечательный `std::sort`.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) вторым параметром передается количество элементов, размер элемента передается третьим параметром, а компаратор только четвертым...

```
qsort(arr, n, sizeof(int), comp);
```

Для тех, кто в танке: по ссылке ясно видно, что компаратор должен быть

```
int comp(const void* i, const void* j)
```

Обратите внимание на `void`. Но это не имеет отношения к вашему вопросу, это уже другая ошибка.

Разжевывая как для милиционера - медленно и два раза:

```
int comp(const void* i, const void* j)
{
    return *(const int*)i - *(const int*)j;
}
```

Comment: Уже даже не удивляюсь, что на любой ответ лепят минус без пояснений :)

Comment: не работает, выдаёт ошибку argument of type "int (*)(const int *i, const int *j)" is incompatible with parameter of type и State Error C2664 'void qsort(void *,size_t,size_t,_CoreCrtNonSecureSearchSortCompareFunction)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'int (__cdecl *)(const int *,const int *)' to '_CoreCrtNonSecureSearchSortCompareFunction

Comment: Перейдите по ссылке в ответе и посмотрите там на пример компаратора. С кастами и т.п. Или [для с++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort)

Comment: Смотрите дополненный ответ. Ну почему всегда надо доводить до полного решения - чтоб все скомпилилось, отработало и препод принял :) - при том, что в вопросе спрашивают о конкретной ошибке? Гуглопрограммисты?

Comment: SODD же, вполне рабочая практика.

Comment: vp_arth, компаратор я как раз таки взял правильный, с примера